# Why isn't my switch statement working in GUI Netbeans?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm working on an assignment that is supposed to take a hurricane category between 1-5 and output the windspeed info for that specific category. The requirements are: include a default statement within the switch statement.

I've tried just about everything and I'm still unable to run the app through successfully. I'm so frustrated since this assignment is due this evening and I've gotten nowhere :(

```
private void btnSelectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
 int category=6;
 String categoryString = this.txtInput.getText();
 switch (category){
 case 1: categoryString = "1";
    this.txtOutput.setText ("Windspeeds for Category 1 are:  74-950 mph or 
64-82 kt or 119-153 km/h");
    break;
 case 2: categoryString = "2";
    this.txtOutput.setText ("Windspeeds for Category 2 are:  96-110 mph or 
83-95 kt or 154-177 km/h");
    break;
 case 3: categoryString = "3";
    this.txtOutput.setText ("Windspeeds for Category 3 are:  111-130 mph or 
96-113 kt or 178-209 km/h");
    break;
 case 4: categoryString = "4";
    this.txtOutput.setText ("Windspeeds for Category 4 are:  131-155 mph or 
114-135 kt or 210-249 km/h");
    break;
 case 5: categoryString = "5";
    this.txtOutput.setText ("Windspeeds for Category 5 are:  Greater than 
155 mph or 135 kt or 249 km/h");
    break;
 default:
    this.lblWindspeedLabel.setText("Please Choose Category from 1 - 5");

this.txtOutput.setText(""+ categoryString);
        }
    }
```

The final output is supposed to show the category's windspeed info but it keeps on saying the default...

Comment: Because `category` is initialized with a value of `6` and you don't ever change it (except in the `switch` which is **on** `category`).

Answer (score 1):

That was happening because you are taking category as the switch parameter which is of integer type and using categoryString as test cases within switch statement which is of string type. that's why non of the cases are passing and the program is skipping to the default case. try this code. should work.

```
    private void btnSelectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
int category=6;
String categoryString = this.txtInput.getText();
switch (categoryString){
case "1";
this.txtOutput.setText ("Windspeeds for Category 1 are:  74-950 mph or 
64-82 kt or 119-153 km/h");
break;
case "2";
this.txtOutput.setText ("Windspeeds for Category 2 are:  96-110 mph or 
83-95 kt or 154-177 km/h");
break;
case "3";
this.txtOutput.setText ("Windspeeds for Category 3 are:  111-130 mph or 
96-113 kt or 178-209 km/h");
break;
case "4";
this.txtOutput.setText ("Windspeeds for Category 4 are:  131-155 mph or 
114-135 kt or 210-249 km/h");
break;
case "5";
this.txtOutput.setText ("Windspeeds for Category 5 are:  Greater than 
155 mph or 135 kt or 249 km/h");
break;
default:
this.lblWindspeedLabel.setText("Please Choose Category from 1 - 5");

this.txtOutput.setText(""+ categoryString);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to get the output with this code :)

Comment: If it helped would you be kind enough to upvote the answer :)

Comment: yeah sure no problem! Also if you don't mind helping me out with my other 2 questions, that would be really appreciated, I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my codes and they're due tonight. I really need help with them @ShivamSingh

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the category to 6 and then switching trough that value. But the value is always 6, so the default block is always called.
You should get the category value from somewhere ( don't know what your application should do .. ).

Comment: I want the application to show the windspeed info for the category the user enters